# Robots.txt: Allow everything but the root directory

Tags: robots.txt, google-search-console

I have a site that is meant to have http://domain.com/blog as the root directory, and any traffic to http://domain.com is redirected to http://domain.com/blog.

This causes a problem cause when I go to Google and do site:domain.com, I see the root directory with the title of one of the first articles on the page. How can I block the root from being crawled, thus not showing up in search?

In webmaster tools I added the site as http://domain.com but I only fetch as google on the /blog directory and other static pages. Is that correct?

I usually know how to do this but this time the site has a sub-directory as the intended root so it's a bit different.

Can someone verify if this will do what I am trying to achieve?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robots.txt does NOT block a crawler from crawling certain webpages. Robots.txt is simply a text file with a set of guidelines that you ask the crawler to follow it does not at any time block a crawler. If you want to block a certain webpage from being crawl/visited - you will then have to block all access to that page, this includes other users that are not crawlers. But since you have already have it to redirect I see no issue.
Also the $ is not a unified standard, neither is Allow(technically). Try to make it focused on specific bots. Google and Bing recognise the Allow keyword, but many other bots does not.

Also your current robots.txt says this: *Do not crawl any pages, but the root*

I recommend this as your robots.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /$
```

This tells all other bots, but google to not crawl your webpage. And it tells the google crawler not to crawl in root, but everything else is allowed.